# VSCode Typescript why suggest "Auto import from 'node:path'"

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a strange problem, I want to use `path.join` with nodejs, when I input `jo` it suggest me to use `Auto import from 'node:path'`, of course this `node:path` is wrong, I don't know what configuration affects this result.

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "ESNext",
        "target": "ES2017",
        "strict": true,
        "lib": ["es2019"],
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "types": ["node"]
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

package.json

```json
{
    ......
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=14.0.0"
    },
    "engineStrict": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^18.0.0",
        "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.2.1",
        "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.2.1",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
        "@types/node": "^14.14.37",
        "jest": "^26.6.3",
        "jest-coverage-badges": "^1.1.2",
        "prettier": "^2.2.1",
        "rollup": "^2.45.2",
        "ts-jest": "^26.5.4",
        "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
        "tslib": "^2.2.0",
        "typescript": "^4.2.4"
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a recent pull request to the DefinitelyTyped repository that caused this. Here's the related pull request: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/51107 . There's some good discussion in it in the comment thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pull request that made this change was here. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/51107

They appear to be discussing reverting the change until a change can be made to the TypeScript compiler to allow packages to define multiple canonical names for an exported module: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42764

This change went into `@types/node@14.14.27`, so in order to fix this problem you'll need to re-install your `@types/node` and set the version to `14.14.26`.

This results in the behavior you're expecting:
[image]

Alternatively, if you need something provided in a later version of `@types/node` and can't revert to an earlier version, you can still access the other import by moving your cursor over the red underlined missing import and using `Ctrl+.` or `Cmd+.` if you're on a mac, and choosing the second option to import from `path` instead of `node:path`. You can also click the little yellow lightbulb above.
[image]